# error trying to send a double to popen

Tags: c++, vector, popen

I have a value that is a double that I am trying to send it to a script as a parameter to popen.
The error I am getting says that my value is not a double?

code:

```
        transform(pricedat.begin(), pricedat.end(), back_inserter(doublePdat), [](string const& val) {return stod(val);});
        transform(markdat.begin(), markdat.end(), back_inserter(doubleMdat), [](string const& val) {return stod(val);});
        auto biggestMy = std::max_element(std::begin(doublePdat), std::end(doublePdat));
        std::cout << "my max is " << *biggestMy << " at position " << std::distance(std::begin(doublePdat), biggestMy) << std::endl;
        auto biggestMark = std::max_element(std::begin(doubleMdat), std::end(doubleMdat));
        std::cout << "market max is " << *biggestMark << " at position " << std::distance(std::begin(doubleMdat), biggestMark) << std::endl;


        if (biggestMy > biggestMark){
                //cout << "test!" << endl;
        }
        else if (biggestMy < biggestMark){
                biggestMark += 0.00000001;
                sprintf(sendbuy,"%20.4f",biggestMark);
                sprintf(command, php oin.php 155 %s",sendbuy);
                FILE *markbuy = popen(command, "r");
                if (markbuy == NULL) perror ("Error opening file");
                while(fgets(buybuff, sizeof(buybuff), markbuy) != NULL){
                        size_t n = strlen(buybuff);
                        //clean '\0' from fgets
                        if (n && buybuff[n - 1] == '\n') buybuff[n - 1] = '\0';
                        if (buybuff[0] != '\0') purchaseid.push_back(buybuff);
                }

        }

}
```

error:

```
.cpp:92:39: warning: format '%f' expects argument of type 'double', but argument 3 has type '__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<double*, std::vector<double> >' [-Wformat]
```

How do i convert a double to char and pass the variable data to popen?

Answer (score 0):

`biggestMy` and `biggestMark` are of iterator type, but you need to supply `sprintf()` with `double`-typed variable.

Thus, change

```
if (biggestMy > biggestMark){
            //cout << "test!" << endl;
}
else if (biggestMy < biggestMark){
    biggestMark += 0.00000001;
    sprintf(sendbuy,"%20.4f",biggestMark);
```

into

```
if (*biggestMy > *biggestMark){
            //cout << "test!" << endl;
}
else if (*biggestMy < *biggestMark){
    *biggestMark += 0.00000001;
    sprintf(sendbuy,"%20.4f",*biggestMark);
```

Comment: @user4294276 if you did quote `php oin.php 155 %s` correctly, then it's another problem in PHP part.

Comment: any thoughts as to why my php script is not accepting a second argument?  https://bpaste.net/show/2289bc8004a3

Comment: I got it. but my program ends in a segment fault.

Comment: It's the sprint that is causing the segment fault too.  cout << command << endl;  shows ->  /usr/bin/php /home/coinz/cryptsy/buycoin.php 155               0.0063
Segmentation fault
 so it is missing half the number   :(

Comment: @user4294276 edited answer. More dereference operators required.

Comment: same segment fault. I think I am increasing my value incorrectly?  *biggestMark += 0.00000001

Comment: same segment fault with -> else if (*biggestMy < *biggestMark){
                *biggestMark += 0.00000001;
                sprintf(sendbuy,"%20.4f",*biggestMark);

Comment: @user4294276 Make sure neither `doublePdat` nor `doubleMdat` is empty.

Comment: I get pasted the segment fault with this ->  sprintf(sendbuy,"%lf",*biggestMark);  but now I am missing the last 2 digits.  :(

Comment: @user4294276 How was `sendbuy` declared?

Comment: Declare `sendbuy` to be long enough and write `sprintf(sendbuy, "%.8lf", *biggestMark);`